# GetRolesForUser returns all roles even though the user is not in any role

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im using SimpleRoleProvider in a Project of mine but when using the method

Roles.GetRolesForUser(username), it returns all roles thats in the database even though the user is not in any role.

Is this a known issue, and is there a way around it?

I suppose i could access the usersInRoles manually, but do I need to do that?

UPDATE:

After a little more investigation i found that it works when i dont use an email-address as
username.

Does anyone know a way to get this working with email address as username?

```
var username = GetUserNameById(id);
var test = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
var temp = test.Contains("Worker");
if (temp)
```

Comment: is username value null ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you provided very little information about your current setup, so I have to use make some educated guesses.

You are talking about the SimpleRoleProvider so you are very likely to use the SimpleRoleProvider in WebMatrx.WebData. The [Sourcecode](https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleRoleProvider.cs) is available on Github so let`s take a look at it:

```
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        if (!InitializeCalled)
        {
            return PreviousProvider.GetRolesForUser(username);
        }
        using (var db = ConnectToDatabase())
        {
            int userId = SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId(db, SafeUserTableName, SafeUserNameColumn, SafeUserIdColumn, username);
            if (userId == -1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, WebDataResources.Security_NoUserFound, username));
            }

            string query = @"SELECT r.RoleName FROM " + UsersInRoleTableName + " u, " + RoleTableName + " r Where (u.UserId = @0 and u.RoleId = r.RoleId) GROUP BY RoleName";
            return db.Query(query, new object[] { userId }).Select<dynamic, string>(d => (string)d[0]).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

As we can see the first thing that this method does is getting the UserId for the supplied Username via SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId() which looks like this:

```
    // Not an override ==> Simple Membership MUST be enabled to use this method
    public int GetUserId(string userName)
    {
        VerifyInitialized();
        using (var db = ConnectToDatabase())
        {
            return GetUserId(db, SafeUserTableName, SafeUserNameColumn, SafeUserIdColumn, userName);
        }
    }

    internal static int GetUserId(IDatabase db, string userTableName, string userNameColumn, string userIdColumn, string userName)
    {
        var result = db.QueryValue(@"SELECT " + userIdColumn + " FROM " + userTableName + " WHERE (UPPER(" + userNameColumn + ") = @0)", userName.ToUpperInvariant());
        if (result != null)
        {
            return (int)result;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

And here it is getting interesting; in the line where the original author constructed the SQL query he is doing something special. He compares the username in it's Uppercase form (because you may set your database to a collation with is case sensitive, and your user registered himself as “David” und is now trying to login as “david” which would only work with a case-insensitive collation)  but makes one mistake. On the right-hand side he is using `username.ToUpperInvariant()` because he knows about the [Turkey Test](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html) and learned that he should compare his strings in a culture-insensitive form but on the left-hand side he just misses it completely and uses TSQL's `UPPER()` function which uses your database collation.

Depending on your chosen username,  database collation and the other usernames in your UserTable `SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId()` still returns a UserId but it's a wrong one.

Please check if this is the case by calling `SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId()` directly, if my guess is right you have two options

1. change the collation of the username colum to something like
   Latin1_General_CI_AI
2. create your own `IRoleProvider` based on `SimpleRoleProvider` and  overwrite `.GetUserId()` with a version that works with your database collation

Comment: To change collation to Latin1_General_CI_AI seems like the easiest solution, but unfortunately
 it did not work.

Im greatful for any other suggestions that might solve the problem.

Comment: @david2342 maybe we could find a solution for your problem if you supply some test data (username`s, and database collation). what about the direct call to SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId() with the email as username what does it return? the correct id or the id of another user?